# Block CNAME redirect from a domain I don't own

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, seo, cname

Someone has registered a domain and is using a CNAME redirect to direct traffic to my site. Google is seeing this as duplicate content and it's affecting my rankings.

Is there anyway of blocking access for traffic that comes to my site through the domainnotundermycontrol.com redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"There is no BAD publicity."

The CNAME is solely a DNS tool.  The request to you server should still be sending a request for the domainnotundermycontrol.com/somepage to your apache server once it gets you're IP from the DNS lookup.  Apache will see the 'ServerName' as domainnotundermycontrol.com

It sounds like the domain which you CAN control has no filtering on server name, only ip, maybe.  Create a vhost for the domainnotundermycontrol.com on your server to catch all requests to that server name and serve up an index file with links to legitimate page you want people to hit or just some adwords.  Then it will no longer be caught by your other vhost.

Enjoy the free traffic.

Comment: Rather than serve a unique file for  domainnotundermycontrol.com, I'd just HTTP 301 redirect all those requests to the canonical domain.

Comment: @FrankFarmer  That's a good option too, the options are endless.  Send them to your favorite politicians homepage :) Better yet, sent them to my blog ;)